# IOS/Storyboard: View of element and selection on screen out of whack

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have been working in storyboard and something strange has happened. When I select an image, instead of the image actually highlighting an area above it is highlighted.  This is true of all the elements in the View Controller.  They are off vertically.

It's possible that in adding and subtracting elements I did something to the top layout but I can't tell what.  All the elements are within a scrollview that, in turn, is within a view and the dimensions for both are set to 0,0,320,1000.  I am not using auto layout.

The app still builds and runs normally but this makes it difficult to work on this screen in storyboard.

Here is a screenshot of the image and selection showing above it:

[image: screenshot of VC]

Anyone seen this or can suggest what could be causing it?